# Is there a way to use figaro with foreman?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, figaro-ruby

I prefer not to use dotenv, but really would like to use the foreman gem. Will it work with figaro?

Currently I use my own yaml files for loading env variables, and I store them in the root of my project under a .env directory. It seems that foreman tries to read a .env file, and chokes on my .env directory.

So alternatively to using figaro, is there a way to change where foreman looks for my env variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using foreman (0.78) with figaro (1.1.1) in my Rails (4.2) app with no problems. Currently, figaro requires that all variables are in `config/application.yml` file or set in `ENV`. Foreman will always try load .env file if it exists (unfortunately they don't distinguish between file and directory in their check) unless you specify your .env files with `- e`

I think you have 3 options:

1) Use figaro and move your custom .yml files into `config/application.yml`

2) Point foreman to a custom .env file as a workaround (it has to exist though):
   touch .emptyenv
   foreman start -e .emptyenv

3) Rename .env directory to something else, e.g. '.custom_env'

I hope that helps.